# segmented control with two views

Tags: ios, view, uisegmentedcontrol

first, I define two views in my ViewController.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIView *view1;
    UITableView *view2;
}
```

I want to switch the two views  by using segmented control.
the UIview  shows buttons (images)and the other shows them in list.

But I have some trouble.

I don't know how to control the two views.
I found that I have made all the objects on [self.view].

I don't understand relationship between superview and subview well. 
Now,I only want to set them on view1, I didn't know how to realize it.

Great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? ...

```
-(IBAction)segmentChanged:(UISegmentedControl*)sender {
    if ([sender tag]==0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [view1 setAlpha:1.0];
            [view2 setAlpha:0.0];
        }];
    } else if ([sender tag]==1) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [view1 setAlpha:0.0];
            [view2 setAlpha:1.0];
        }];
    }
}
```

Instead of setAlpha you can use setFrame to move the view out of the visible area...

Comment: instead of setting the alpha or the frame, you can also toggle the views' visibility via the .hidden property of UIVIew.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked the code, but it should work :-

```
-(IBAction)segmentChanged:(UISegmentedControl*)sender {
    if (sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        view1.alpha = 0;
        view1.hidden = NO;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [view1 setAlpha:1.0];
            [view2 setAlpha:0.0];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){ [view2 setHidden:YES]; }];
    } else {
        view2.alpha = 0;
        view2.hidden = NO;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            [view2 setAlpha:1.0];
            [view1 setAlpha:0.0];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished){ [view1 setHidden:YES]; }];
    }
}
```

and in viewDidLoad set

```
view2.hidden = YES;
self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
```

Comment: eh... Thanks a lot.  And how to make the segmented button still visible in view2?  en...    my table view is not initialized yet....I am filling  cells now...

Comment: segmented button, view1 and view2 should be subviews of the main view of your viewController

Comment: Just use .hidden OR .alpha and not both, thats useless.

Comment: Setting alpha value zero will visibly hide the view but that view will still be there and it will take touch events, so you have to remove the view from its parent hierarchy or set its hidden value to "YES"